# Why do I get a cast exception in the "for each" and not in the "for"?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, casting

I would expect the two fors in the following code to behave the same way but they don't:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Appender> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Appender.class);
Mockito.verify(mockedAppender, times(3)).doAppend(argumentCaptor.capture());

for(int i = 0; i< argumentCaptor.getAllValues().size(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(((LoggingEvent) argumentCaptor.getAllValues().get(i)).getMessage());
}

for(Appender appender : argumentCaptor.getAllValues()) {
     System.out.println(((LoggingEvent) appender).getMessage());
}
```

The first correctly prints the messages while the second gives me this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent
>   cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.core.Appender

Comment: You fail to cast something into `Appender`, so I guess the type within the foreach loop header is wrong

Comment: Try `for (LoggingEvent appender : argumentCaptor.getAllValues())`

Comment: I believe object returned by argumentCaptor.getAllValues().get(i) can be casted to both Appender and LoggingEvent  but Appender  cannot be casted to LoggingEvent

Comment: I think `ArgumentCaptor<Appender> argumentCaptor` is wrong here. You actually capture `LoggingEvent`s, so it should be `ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent>`.

Comment: Hm, does it even compile?

Comment: The code compiles the way it is. If i try to change the code to ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> or the foreach to for(LoggingEvent :argumentCaptor.getAllValues()) then it doesn't compile anymore

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the casting inside the print function.

I think the problem is in this:

```
for(Appender appender : argumentCaptor.getAllValues()) { ...
```

Change it to

```
for(LoggingEvent loggingEvent : argumentCaptor.getAllValues()) {
     System.out.println(loggingEvent.getMessage());
}
```